# mysqlbinlog command hangs when pipe to mysql (MySQL server has gone away)

Tags: mysql

I have tried to execute this command several times and it always hangs, but the recovery finish (I've checked the data, seems to be finished).

```
[root@server]# ps -ef|grep -i mysql
mysql     97348      1  2 10:44 ?        00:00:46 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
root      97659  97628  0 10:57 pts/1    00:00:01 mysqlbinlog --start-position=154 mysql-bin.000020 mysql-bin.000021 mysql-bin.000022 mysql-bin.000023 mysql-bin.000024 mysql-bin.000025 mysql-bin.000026 mysql-bin.000027 mysql-bin.000028 mysql-bin.000029 mysql-bin.000030 mysql-bin.000031 mysql-bin.000032
root      97660  97628 98 10:57 pts/1    00:21:18 mysql --init-command=SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;
```

There is no process for the operation, only my current shell process.

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
|  9 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does someone know way it keep running even when the recovery finish?

EDIT:

After some time, I got the error

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1867988: MySQL server has gone away
```

Before import the data, I've already tried using the following parameters

```
SET GLOBAL net_buffer_length=1048576; 
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

Comment: How long before it timed out?  What does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';` say?

Comment: This is most likely due to mem limits. For Linux run a 'ulimit -a' / adjust. Also your mem limits config for mysql in the cnf file.